# How to change google.maps.InfoWindow propreties?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm now trying to customize my `InfoWindow`, that appears when i click on my google map markers:

here is my code:

```
var contentString =
'<div><div style="color:#FFFFFF; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold;width:100%;'+
'background-image:url(\'myImage.png\'); padding:7px;">'+
'colorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcol<br>'+
'colorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcol<br>'+
'colorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcol<br>'+
'colorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcol<br></div></div></div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            padding: 0
            });
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

The Gray div is my content.

How can i modify my `InfoWindow` propreties like `padding`, so my content can fit   the `InfoWindow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html)

There are some examples of how to use it and it provides a lot of customization options.